# Move billions of records from one table to another in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a teradata view, containing 1 billion records for each day and I need to process data for 1 year, so we have 365 billion records and Data is partitioned by date - interval each day.

I need to Insert - select 3 ID columns(data will be grouped based on these) and 2 columns with measures (need to use SUM agg function)

Query is something like below:

```
Insert into table1
Select 
  col1, col2, col3, SUM(col4), SUM(col5)
FROM 
  table2
GROUP BY 
  col1, col2, col3
WHERE coldate between 'date1' and 'date2';
```

The issue is that query keeps executing (didnt complete in 20 mins) if I run it for one day and I need to run this for 1 year.

How should I approach - should I use MLOAD - insert select or what else?

Please suggest, need resolution asap. Thanks

```
Explain SELECT 
    ORIGINATING_NUMBER_VAL,
    SUM(ACTIVITY_DURATION_MEAS),
    SUM(Upload_Data_Volume),
    SUM(Download_Data_Volume)
FROM 
    dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES
WHERE
    CAST(Activity_Start_Dttm as DATE) between '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-31'
GROUP BY 
    ORIGINATING_NUMBER_VAL;

  1) First, we lock DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES for access, we lock
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLC_2013 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES for access, we lock
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ4_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES for access, we lock
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES_BLC in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES for access, we lock
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ2_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES for access, we lock
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ1_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES for access, and we lock
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ3_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES for access.
  2) Next, we do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from 31 partitions of
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES with a condition of (
     "(DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '2014-12-01 00:00:00') AND
     ((DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '3015-02-09 00:00:00') AND
     (DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm <
     TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00'))") into Spool 1 (all_amps), which
     is built locally on the AMPs.  The input table will not be cached
     in memory, but it is eligible for synchronized scanning.  The size
     of Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be 1 row (70 bytes).
     The estimated time for this step is 37.22 seconds.
  3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from 31 partitions of
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES_BLC in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES with a condition of (
     "(DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES_BLC in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '2014-12-01 00:00:00') AND
     ((DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES_BLC in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm <
     TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00') AND
     ((DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES_BLC in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '2014-10-13 00:00:00') AND
     (DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES_BLC in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm <
     TIMESTAMP '3015-02-10 00:00:00')))") into Spool 1 (all_amps),
     which is built locally on the AMPs.  The input table will not be
     cached in memory, but it is eligible for synchronized scanning.
     The result spool file will not be cached in memory.  The size of
     Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be 22,856,337,679 rows
     (1,599,943,637,530 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 1
     hour and 52 minutes.
  4) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from 0 partitions of
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ1_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES by way of an all-rows scan
     with a condition of ("(DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ1_14 in
     view dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '2014-12-01 00:00:00') AND
     ((DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ1_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm<
     TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00') AND
     ((DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ1_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm <
     TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 00:00:00') AND
     (DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ1_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '2014-01-01 00:00:00')))") into Spool 1 (all_amps),
     which is built locally on the AMPs.  The input table will not be
     cached in memory, but it is eligible for synchronized scanning.
     The size of Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be
     22,856,337,680 rows (1,599,943,637,600 bytes).  The estimated time
     for this step is 0.01 seconds.
  5) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from 0 partitions of
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ2_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES by way of an all-rows scan
     with a condition of ("(DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ2_14 in
     view dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '2014-12-01 00:00:00') AND
     ((DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ2_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm<
     TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00') AND
     ((DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ2_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm <
     TIMESTAMP '2014-07-01 00:00:00') AND
     (DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ2_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 00:00:00')))") into Spool 1 (all_amps),
     which is built locally on the AMPs.  The input table will not be
     cached in memory, but it is eligible for synchronized scanning.
     The size of Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be
     22,856,337,681 rows (1,599,943,637,670 bytes).  The estimated time
     for this step is 0.01 seconds.
  6) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from 0 partitions of
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ3_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES by way of an all-rows scan
     with a condition of ("(DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ3_14 in
     view dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '2014-12-01 00:00:00') AND
     ((DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ3_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm<
     TIMESTAMP '2014-10-01 00:00:00') AND
     ((DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ3_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '2014-07-01 00:00:00') AND
     (DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ3_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm <
     TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00')))") into Spool 1 (all_amps),
     which is built locally on the AMPs.  The input table will not be
     cached in memory, but it is eligible for synchronized scanning.
     The size of Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be
     22,856,337,682 rows (1,599,943,637,740 bytes).  The estimated time
     for this step is 0.01 seconds.
  7) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from 0 partitions of
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ4_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES by way of an all-rows scan
     with a condition of ("(DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ4_14 in
     view dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '2014-12-01 00:00:00') AND
     ((DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ4_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm<
     TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00') AND
     ((DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ4_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm <
     TIMESTAMP '2014-10-13 00:00:00') AND
     (DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLCQ4_14 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '2014-10-01 00:00:00')))") into Spool 1 (all_amps),
     which is built locally on the AMPs.  The input table will not be
     cached in memory, but it is eligible for synchronized scanning.
     The size of Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be
     22,856,337,683 rows (1,599,943,637,810 bytes).  The estimated time
     for this step is 0.01 seconds.
  8) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from 0 partitions of
     DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLC_2013 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES by way of an all-rows scan
     with a condition of ("(DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLC_2013 in
     view dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm >=
     TIMESTAMP '2014-12-01 00:00:00') AND
     ((DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLC_2013 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm<
     TIMESTAMP '2014-01-01 00:00:00') AND
     (DP_TAB.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_BLC_2013 in view
     dp_tab_view.NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.Activity_Start_Dttm <
     TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00'))") into Spool 1 (all_amps), which
     is built locally on the AMPs.  The input table will not be cached
     in memory, but it is eligible for synchronized scanning.  The size
     of Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be 22,856,337,684
     rows (1,599,943,637,880 bytes).  The estimated time for this step
     is 0.01 seconds.
  9) We do an all-AMPs SUM step to aggregate from Spool 1 (Last Use) by
     way of an all-rows scan with a condition of (
     "((CAST((NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.ACTIVITY_START_DTTM) AS
     DATE))>= DATE '2014-12-01') AND
     ((CAST((NETWORK_ACTIVITY_DATA_RES.ACTIVITY_START_DTTM) AS DATE))<=
     DATE '2014-12-31')") , grouping by field1 ( ORIGINATING_NUMBER_VAL).
     Aggregate Intermediate Results are computed globally, then placed
     in Spool 4.  The aggregate spool file will not be cached in memory.
     The size of Spool 4 is estimated with low confidence to be
     17,142,253,263 rows (1,628,514,059,985 bytes).  The estimated time
     for this step is 6 hours and 28 minutes.
 10) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from Spool 4 (Last Use) by way of
     an all-rows scan into Spool 2 (group_amps), which is built locally
     on the AMPs.  The result spool file will not be cached in memory.
     The size of Spool 2 is estimated with low confidence to be
     17,142,253,263 rows (1,165,673,221,884 bytes).  The estimated time
     for this step is 21 minutes and 27 seconds.
 11) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> The contents of Spool 2 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.  The total estimated time is 8 hours and 42 minutes.
```

Comment: What are the indexes and plan? Looks like 'range'-type query which denies any composite indexing. Group'ing 1 bln. of unindexed records is both memory- and time-consuming task.

Comment: What is the PI of the target table? Does it match the source table? If it does not, is it possible that you have a skewing issue on the redistribution step in the query plan. A partition with 1 billion rows is fairly deep but depending on the system configuration not unmanageable. Are your stats collected based on recommended practices for PPI tables?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, below is the execution plan for the select query (considering 1 month), total time estimate is 8 hours plus. Please advise. 

https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=73d6f5250a5bffa7&id=73D6F5250A5BFFA7!256&ithint=file,txt&authkey=!ABNlAtlSDyGDaLI

Comment: You'll probably want to insure that your target table is a Multiset table, and not a Set table. INSERTs are slow on SET tables since each inserted record needs to be checked for uniqueness against every existing record.

Comment: Thanks.. I created target table as multiset and created similar primary index and range partitions as the source table.

Insert with aggregation of one month data (approx 30 billion records) executed in 2 hours. This is acceptable for present requirement. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the target table as MULTISET, as suggested by @JNevill is always a good idea. Other than that there's not much you can do, as the plan looks reasonable as it is.

Since you seem to have daily partitions in the source table (`We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from 31 partitions of`), you could run a series of smaller daily queries - it wouldn't be any faster, but:

- you'd get your results incrementally,
- in case of failure you won't have to start over after the query running for hours
- you'll have better ETA, since you'll have the actual execution time for the first few days soon. The figures in EXPLAIN may be very different from the actual time.